# Hot to set R home directory in r.net on docker/Debian?

Tags: c#, r, docker, r.net

I try to use R.Net in an asp.net Razor App with docker support. The docker image is Debian 10, R is installed in the image under the standard path `/usr/lib/R`. When executing

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(rHome:"/usr/lib/R"); // or any other path including none
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
```

I obtain the error `R home directory is not defined`. If I open a shell into my container and start R, `R.home()` returns `/usr/lib/R`. So it looks as if R in the container has a R home directory set, but r.net isn't recognizing it? Any ideas what I could try to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *most likely* invoke R the wrong way. Use `/usr/bin/R` which is a frontend which sets `R_HOME` for further use by the other components.

```
edd@rob:~$ file /usr/bin/R
/usr/bin/R: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
edd@rob:~$ grep ^R_HOME /usr/bin/R 
R_HOME_DIR=/usr/lib/R
R_HOME="${R_HOME_DIR}"
edd@rob:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It seemed indeed, that I was starting R differently from the console in the docker container and from asp.net. Now I set the environmental variable in my dockerfile `ENV R_HOME=/usr/lib/R` and R.NET seems to work.